# asterisk call from file

Tags: call, asterisk, dialplan

i want to use the call from file system.

the file.call looks like this:

```
;------------------------------------

Channel: Dongle/dongle0/07xxxxxxxx

MaxRetries: 2

RetryTime: 60

WaitTime: 30

Context: testing

Extension: 07xxxxxxxx

CallerID: 07xxxxxxxy

Priority: 1

;------------------------------------
```

extension.cof like this:

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[testing]

exten => s,1,Answer()

exten => s,n(lbl_testing_0),Set(TIMEOUT(response)=10)

exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=1)

exten => s,n,Background(custom/nice_sound)

exten => s,n,WaitExten(10,m())

exten => s,n,Hangup()

exten => 1,1,SayDigits(1)

exten => 1,n,Playback(tts/sound1)

;exten => 1,n,System(/bin/echo "peresed key 1 and save in txt and mysql after" >> /var/spool/asterisk/key1.txt)

exten => 1,n,MYSQL(Connect connid 127.0.0.1 asterisk password asterisk)

exten => 1,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`,`number`,`date`) VALUES (${EXTEN},${CALLERID(num)},now()))

exten => 1,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})

exten => 1,n(lbl_testing_1),Hangup()

exten => 2,1,SayDigits(3)

exten => 2,n,Playback(tts/sound2)

exten => 2,n,Goto(1,lbl_testing_1)

exten => 3,1,SayDigits(3)

exten => 3,n,Playback(tts/sound3)

exten => 3,n,Goto(1,lbl_testing_1)

exten => 4,1,Playback(tts/sound4)

exten => 4,n,Goto(s,lbl_testing_0)

exten => i,1,Playback(invalidValue)

exten => i,n,Goto(s,lbl_testing_0)

exten => t,1,Playback(timeout)

exten => t,n,Goto(s,lbl_testing_0)

exten => 111,1,Dial(PJSIP/111)

exten => 111,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CHANUNAVAIL"]?lbl_testing_3:)

exten => 111,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?lbl_testing_3:)

exten => 111,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?lbl_testing_3:)

exten => 111,n(lbl_testing_2),Hangup()

exten => 111,n(lbl_testing_3),VoiceMail(testing@111,s)

exten => 111,n,Goto(lbl_testing_2)

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Somehow it works.

The question is: how do i put this dialplan only in the file.call and no longer use [testing] from extension.conf and all the settings to make it in that file.call that i automatically move to /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing

I tried like this:

```
;------------------------------------

Channel: Dongle/dongle0/07xxxxxxxx

MaxRetries: 2

RetryTime: 60

WaitTime: 30

Extension: 07xxxxxxxx

CallerID: 07xxxxxxxy

Application: Playback

Data: custom/nice_sound

;------------------------------------
```

but i can't find how to add the rest of the dialplan settings and save in mysql

does anyone know how? is it possible to work like this or i'm too dreamy?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Call files designed to make call request. It not intended to use as dialplan replacement.

There is no way to put complex dialplan in callfile.

Only things you can do is set some variables via Set: construction and use CDR for mysql.